# Steam API Multiple SteamIDs

Tags: php, steam, steamworks-api

I'm trying to generate a HTML Table for multiple SteamIDs which are in my MySQL Database. My Database looks like this:

`id | steamid64 | xenforo_username | xenforo_userid`

```
 /*
  * Accountlist Query
  */
  $list = $db->query('SELECT * FROM steamlist ORDER BY id DESC');
  $list = $list->fetch_assoc();

  /*
  * Parse Query Values into Strings
  */
  $steamid = $list['steamid64'];
  $xfUsername = $list['xf_username'];
  $xfUserid = $list['xf_userid'];

  /*
  * Create array for the list
  */
  $steamlist = array( array("Forum Username | "=>$xfUsername, "Steam Username | "=>$steamapi->personaname, "SteamID | "=>$steamid, "Last Logout | "=>$steamapi->lastlogoff, "Onlinestatus"=>$steamapi->personastate)
              );

  /*
  * API URL
  */
    $api_url=file_get_contents("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=$api_key&format=json&steamids=$steamid");
    $api_url = json_decode($api_url);

  /*
  * Parse API URL into variable
  */
  $steamapi = $api_url->response->players[0];
```

I belive I'm in need of a foreach-function to get the information from the SteamAPI for all SteamIDs which are stored in my DB. Could someone maybe help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>STEAMID</th>
        <th>USER NAME</th>
        <th>USER ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--Use a while loop to make a table row for every DB row-->
    <?php while( $row = $list->fetch()) : ?>
    <tr>
        <!--Each table column is echoed in to a td cell-->
        <td><?php echo $row['steamid64']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['xf_username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['xf_userid']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: while loop is good for such problem, you should embed this in your .html file or document

Comment: Hey, thanks for your post. The problem is, this won't help me much, since I need to send all SteamIDs to the WebAPI of Steam. Any idea how I do that? :S

Comment: Hello, that calls for json, encode on your file which outputs the  php array, and then decode on your WebAPI, You should then use javascript to display the data